# Serializing with namespace declaration on childnode with XmlSerializer

Tags: c#, xmlserializer

I'm trying to serialize using XMLSerializer and achieve the following result:

Desired xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RootElem xmlns="http://www.example.com/rootns">
  <Elem1>
    <Foo>bar</Foo>
  </Elem1>
  <Elem2>
    <x:ElemX xmlns:x="http://www.sample.net/otherns">
      <x:Bar>foo</x:Bar>
    </x:ElemX>
  </Elem2>
</RootElem>
```

The content in `<elem3>` will be parsed alone by a system on the other end, so the xmlns:x specification will have to be on the `<elemx>` node, and not on the rootnode as below.

Current serialized xml, not desired:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RootElem xmlns:x="http://www.sample.net/otherns" xmlns="http://www.example.com/rootns">
  <Elem1>
    <Foo>bar</Foo>
  </Elem1>
  <Elem2>
    <x:ElemX>
      <x:Bar>foo</x:Bar>
    </x:ElemX>
  </Elem2>
</RootElem>
```

Anyone know a standard way to instruct XmlSerializer to achieve this?

Here's the code used to generate this sample (simple c# winform application)

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RootElem root = new RootElem();

        root.Elem1 = new NormalElement() { Foo = "bar"};

        ChildClass c = new ChildClass() { Bar = "foo"};
        root.Elem2 = new ElementWithChildClass() { ElemX = c };

        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();

        XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
        ns.Add("x", "http://www.sample.net/otherns");

        XmlSerializer xser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(RootElem));
        XmlTextWriter tw = new XmlTextWriter(ms, Encoding.UTF8);
        tw.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;

        xser.Serialize(tw, root, ns);

        ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(ms, Encoding.UTF8);
        textBox1.Text = sr.ReadToEnd();
    }


    [XmlRoot(Namespace = "http://www.example.com/rootns")]
    public class RootElem
    {
        public NormalElement Elem1 { get; set; }
        public ElementWithChildClass Elem2 { get; set; }
    }

    public class NormalElement
    {
        public string Foo { get; set; }
    }

    public class ElementWithChildClass
    {
        [XmlElement(Namespace = "http://www.sample.net/otherns")]
        public ChildClass ElemX  { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot("RefDoc", Namespace = "http://www.sample.net/otherns")]
    public class ChildClass
    {
        public string Bar { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Can the system that will be parsing not be fixed so that it respects `XML` and not "sorta-kinda XML, but actually we're going to do things that then break normal XML tools"

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, Yeah that would be great, also not happening (I unfortunately have no control of the system on the other end)